# How to create a chart in WPF using CSV file?

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, plot

I have been using Python libraries to do this, which is pretty much easy work. But now I am supposed to do this in WPF/c#, I am using a template dashboard that already has a custom chart[(here is the chart I have)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlNpt.png) but hence that I am new to the language and WPF I have problems plotting the data that I have.

My program first connects to an SFTP server afterward downloads the file and now I am at the step to read that file and show it in a graph.

My `getData` function works like this:

```
String Host = "**.***.***.***";
int Port = 22;
String RemoteFileName = "/var/test.csv";
String LocalDestinationFilename = @"in_process/test.csv";
String Username = "***";
String Password = "*****";
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password))
{
    sftp.Connect();  
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(LocalDestinationFilename)) 
    {
        FileSize = sftp.Get(RemoteFileName).Attributes.Size;
        sftp.DownloadFile(RemoteFileName, file); 
    }
    sftp.Disconnect();  
}
```

So after this, The file is being downloaded will look like this: [here is the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL5a1.png)
I have to make computer read this and find the correct chart and plot them in. and show it in WPF what are the options I have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem, here we have two steps:

1. Read a CSV file and store data in memory
2. Display data as in chart

For the first you can use a Nuget package like [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/) to parse your CSV file.

And for the second, you can use another package like [Oxyplot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot)

Bot of theses packages are free (MIT License).

And of course, you will need a WPF application with (at least) a window.